# Node.js - Help Converting XML to Custom JSON

Tags: javascript, xml, json, node.js

I'm building a xml to json function which converts our XML structure to a specifically formatted JSON.

I've tried many libraries, and ultimately, I've settled on just turning the XML into a DOM tree that I can walk and convert to JSON myself because the libraries don't provide the format I need.

So here's an example xml document:

```
var xml = '<document>' +
            '<divisions>' +
              '<division id="123" division="foo">' +
                '<departments>' +
                  '<department id="456" department="bar"/>'+
                  '<department id="678" department="bar"/>'+
                '</departments>' +
              '</division>' +
            '</divisions>' +

            '<roles>' +
              '<role id="123" name="foo"/>' +
              '<role id="123" name="foo"/>' +
            '</roles>' +
          '</document>';
```

**Desired output:**

```
{ divisions: [ { id: '123', division: 'foo', departments: [ { id: '456', department: 'bar' } ] } ], roles: [ { id: '123', name: 'foo'}, { id: '123', name: 'foo'} ] }
```

Here's my initial stab at it:

```
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

function XMLtoJSON(xml) {

  var json = {};
  var dom  = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml).childNodes[0];

  function process(nodes, parent) {

    var node, name, hasChildren;

    for(var i = 0, l = nodes.length; i < l; i++) {

      node        = nodes[i];
      name        = node.tagName;
      hasChildren = node.hasChildNodes();

      if(!parent) {
        json[name] = [];
      }

      if(node.hasAttributes()) {

        var attributes = node.attributes, obj = {};
        for(var x = 0, al = attributes.length; x < al; x++) {

          obj[attributes[x].name] = attributes[x].value;

          if(!parent) {
            json[name].push(obj);
          }
        }
      }

      if(hasChildren) {
        process(nodes[i].childNodes);
      }
    }
  }

  process(dom.childNodes);

  return json;
}

console.log( XMLtoJSON(xml) );
```

Currently, this will output:

```
{ divisions: [],
  division: 
   [ { id: '123', division: 'foo' },
     { id: '123', division: 'foo' } ],
  departments: [],
  department: 
   [ { id: '678', department: 'bar' },
     { id: '678', department: 'bar' } ],
  roles: [],
  role: [ { id: '123', name: 'foo' }, { id: '123', name: 'foo' } ] }
```

**Note:** I don't want to the parent `document` in my json, thus the initial `parseFromString(xml).childNodes[0];`

I'm wondering if anyone can help get me a little closer. Specifically, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to handle embedded collections (departments is an array within divisions). I've been working on this for a few hours and the recursion keeps tripping me up.

Comment: I don't see any place where `process` gets called with the `parent` argument, so I'm curious about why it's tested twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it took so long to answer. This was kind of hard one. Following code works at least with you current example XML. Tricky part is to decide which elements are arrays and which elements are not. The logic here is that everything with attributes is object and everything else is array.

```
function DOMToObject (node, obj, isArray) {

    var child = node.firstChild,
        attributes,
        newObj,
        i,
        j,
        k = 0;

    if (!obj) {
        obj = {};
    }

    while (child) {

        attributes = child.attributes;

        if (attributes && attributes.length) {

            newObj = {};
            DOMToObject(child, newObj);

            for (i = 0, j = attributes.length; i < j; i++) {
                newObj[attributes[i].name] = attributes[i].value;
            }

        } else {

            newObj = [];
            DOMToObject(child, newObj, true);
        }

        if (isArray) {
            obj[k] = newObj;
            k += 1;

        } else {
            obj[child.nodeName] = newObj;
        }

        child = child.nextSibling;
    }

    return obj;
};

var JSON = JSON.stringify(DOMToObject(dom.firstChild));
```